# How to create multiple requests in Postman via a for loop?

Tags: postman

hi,

I want to POST requests to Postman, to the same endpoint, using a variable ('ID') that will have values ranging from 1-10000, in order.
This is what i did:

```
**JSON Request:**
{
    "UCPID": "{{ID}}",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Ref1":"LVM",
            "Ref2":"DLV",
            "Ref3":"DLV",
            "StartDate":"2016-05-08",
            "EndDate":"2016-05-12",
            ..
}
```

```
**In the Pre-request script:**
/*jshint loopfunc:true */

var count;
for(count = 0; count < 10000; count++){
    pm.globals.set("ID", count);
console.log("value:" + count);
//var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
//tests["ucp id = " + count] = true;              // debug message

pm.sendRequest("https://postman-echo.com/get", function (err, response) {
    console.log(response.json());
});
}
```

I expected this to run 10000 times; instead, it runs once only!

I know that Postman allows for data files in CSV to be passed in Postman's Runner; but i dont want to do this, my IDs are simply 1 to 10000, i dont want to have to create a CSV for this.. i want to do this programmatically! 
Am i missing something ? 
thanks!
Matt

Comment: where is your 'ID' used ? in your postman-echo get request there is no json body and I can't see your parameter ? it seems that you don't use your global ... Do you do this in your pre-request script ? in your Tests tab ?

Comment: right, you re correct . I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did, in Pre-request script:

```
 pm.globals.set("ID", '\"'+Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)+1) +'\"');
```

Thus i didnt need to use a CSV anymore

Comment: How does this work to run 1000 times? Where do you set it up to run this many times?